# Tmux Keyboard Shortcut

Tags: tmux

I pasted the following into my ~/.tmux.conf

`bind -n <C-w>h run "(tmux display-message -p '#{pane_current_command}' | grep -iq vim && tmux send-keys C-h) || tmux select-pane -L"`

It now yields the error:

`/home/machine/.tmux.conf:2: unknown key: <C-w>h`

I am trying to mimic the vim command " + h" switches to the left buffer.

Answer (score 0):

The only multi-key bindings that `tmux` accepts are those single keys preceded by the `tmux` prefix (<kbd>Control</kbd>-<kbd>b</kbd> by default), which is implicit when using `bind` without the `-n` flag. With the flag, you are telling `tmux` to use the single key itself, not in combination the prefix. Otherwise, you *cannot* create multi-key bindings in `tmux`.